# How efficient is XAML parsing in WinRT / Win8?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

When creating UserControls, it looks like the XAML is being parsed every time the control is initialized.

For example, when I create a UserControl, there's auto-generated code to initialize the component that looks like this:

```
public void InitializeComponent()
{
    if (_contentLoaded)
        return;

    _contentLoaded = true;
    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(this, new global::System.Uri("ms-appx:///Views/MyView.xaml"), global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ComponentResourceLocation.Application);

}
```

This existed in Silverlight as well.

Creating the control once or twice is not a big deal, but if I have a large visual tree in each UserControl with Visual-States and bindings, and I'm creating it many times per application lifecycle, it would make sense to build the visual controls using C# to boost performance.

**So, my question is:**

Does the parser/framework "remember" the XAML file and avoid re-parsing it again on subsequent calls? That is, does it create a binary representation of the XAML so it doesn't have to read text all over again?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that XAML gets compiled into a binary form as a resource within your application. The runtime does not have to parse the text of the .xaml file, just as it does not have to parse your .cs code files.

The performance of instantiating the classes as declared with XAML is supposed to be on par with creating it in code.

Comment: This was the case in WPF. When you compile your libraries, it generated code files and BAML files. But in Silverlight and WinRT, there's no BAML, and if you peek into the compiled DLLs, they actually have the XAML files in plain text. So I'm suspicious of the behavior in the LoadComponent(...) method.

Comment: It seems like they added binary serialization of XAML in Silverlight for Windows Phone 8, but I never heard of it being done in Windows 8. It might be worth checking the performance difference, but my guess is it might be fairly negligible compared to handling layout updates.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 xaml finally added XAML binary format :)

XAML Binary Format: The final signed appx will no longer contain text based markup as it will get converted into Binary.